# Unity coroutine (MEC) not calling

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to load an image from a Firestore storage url, by calling a coroutine (using more efficient coroutines asset).
However, the coroutine isn't calling and I can't figure out why...

```
public void displayImage(string url)
{
   Debug.Log("called display image: "+ url); 
   
Timing.RunCoroutine(_loadImageSingle(url));
}

 public IEnumerator<float> _loadImageSingle(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading ....");
    WWW wwwLoader = new WWW(url); 
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(wwwLoader);
  
   
    singleimg.texture = wwwLoader.texture;
}
```

Any pointers really appreciated!

Comment: You have to use `StartCoroutine(_loadImageSingle(url))`.

Answer (score 0):

[Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in Unity are only `IEnumerator` withouth any return value!

And then you have to run it using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) ... I guess this happens in the code you didn't show?

```c#
public void displayImage(string url)
{
   Debug.Log("called display image: "+ url); 

   Timing.RunCoroutine(_loadImageSingle(url));
}

private IEnumerator _loadImageSingle(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading ....");
    WWW wwwLoader = new WWW(url); 

    yield return Timing.WaitUntilDone(wwwLoader);
  
    singleimg.texture = wwwLoader.texture;
}
```

---

In general note that `WWW` is **obsolete**. You should rather use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html):

```c#
private IEnumerator _loadImageSingle(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading ....");
    
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get downloaded texture
            singleimg.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Many thanks! Up and working now :) 

Although in a related issue...

I'm calling this coroutine from a method that returns the download url from firebase storage : 


`img1_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) => {
  if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled) {
  

    UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() => UIcontroller.displayImage(task.Result.ToString()));


  }
});`

If I wanted to find the URL of two files, and then pass to the coroutines to download, how would I 'chain' those together....?

Comment: This is a well known issue: `ContinueWith` is executed on a background thread. Rather use [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) in order to do what the name says ;) Then either implement a method for multiple parallel downloads or chained downloads using e.g. a list of strings?

Comment: aaaahhhh got it...

I really need to do some reading about threading.... 

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Actually WWW is obsolete. You should use UnityWebRequestTexture. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html)

Comment: @Thomas as I already said at the bottom of the answer ;)